# .htaccess автоматически добавлять слэш

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Всем привет , прописал подобные строки в .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ru/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

все работает как надо , только вот еще нужно чтобы например
если юзер ввел в адресной строку `127.0.0.1/en` ( без обратного слэша)
слэш автоматически дополнялся в адресную строку , как так сделать?

`127.0.0.1/en/` все работает

`127.0.0.1/en` при наборе в адресной строку выходит подобное `127.0.0.1/en/en`

Answer (score 2):

Есть 2 варианта решения.

**1. Изменение условия RewriteCond, чтобы предотвратить обработку запросов вида host/language.**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|ru)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Обратите внимание на символ `$` в условии RewriteCond, он нужен, чтобы запросы вроде /enterprise не отбрасывались, а приводились к виду /en/enterprise.

**2. Добавление слэша к запросу вида host/language.**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/(en|ru)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|ru)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Первое RewriteRule добавляет слэш.

**Какой вариант мне выбрать?**

Второй вариант имеет смысл использовать, если для сервера есть разница между запросами /en и /en/, например, может быть настроен прокси для директории en. В противном случае я бы выбрал первый вариант как более компактный и не содержащий повторения "en|ru".

Answer (score 1):

Решено , надо было добавить еще исключение для папки /en (без слэша)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en             //вот что добавил
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ru/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ru             //вот что добавил
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```